# Use Jenkins container to build Dockerfile and deploy Flask app

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose

I have a Flask-Nginx app that I made using Flask and Nginx Docker containers and used docker-compose to make them run. Now I want to use a Jenkins container to clone this code from a repository upon a Web-hook trigger. This means I have to build and run my Flask app container inside a container (Docker in Docker). Is this a correct approach(It feels messy to me)? Or is there anyway to build and run the Flask app container outside the Jenkins container? Please let me know of any other possible and proper ways.

Answer (score 0):

yes, There is an option that's **Kaniko**.

You wouldn't need docker to build a docker image from a Dockerfile.
Sounds impossible then check out Kaniko.

One more bonus of using kaniko is that the images built by it are identical to the images built by Docker.
Check out
https://medium.com/@sebgoa/building-docker-images-with-kaniko-6e2421b018